# How to add columns in existing database table in code first approach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2

I have two projects in my solution, one is simple mvc project and the other one is web api.I have used Entity Framework. I have also used asp.net identity which generated the local db that has many columns in AspNetUsers table. Now I want to add and delete some columns from AspNetUsers table.
I have included Migrations folder in my project which has configuration.cs and initial create.cs classes

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUsers",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Email = c.String(maxLength: 256),
                    EmailConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    PasswordHash = c.String(),
                    SecurityStamp = c.String(),
                    PhoneNumber = c.String(),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    LockoutEndDateUtc = c.DateTime(),
                    LockoutEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    UserName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                    })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.UserName, unique: true, name: "UserNameIndex");
```

I have also tried to update database using Package Manager Console but nothing happened.
So how can I add another column in AspNetUsers table?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add new properties to `AspNetUsers` entity, then use `add-migration` command refer https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/#Add-Migration also refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to add Codes to create the Table yourself. The Migrations can do everything for you.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    ... Your Codes ...

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and just run the Code in PackageManager:

```
add-migration somenotehere
```

it will create a Migration for your database.
then all you have to do is to commit the Changes to ddl.

So run this Code in PackageManager:

```
update-database
```

Hope it works.